# Is there a nice well-behaved order isomorphism between the real algebraic numbers and the rationals?

Tags: order-theory

Via Cantor's back-and-forth method we know that the linearly ordered set of all rational numbers and the linearly ordered set of all real algebraic numbers are isomorphic.

But from the point of view of what people usually do with rational numbers or with algebraic numbers, the order isomorphisms yielded by Cantor's proof are icky.

Are there any that are well behaved and have nice mathematical properties?

Comment: You have added a really useful technical term to discussion of mathematics. I am envious, and will likely steal it.

Comment: You know, I think I have a better reason to argue for the impossibility result in my answer. Are there even any explicit (choice-free) bijections from $\Bbb N$ to the algebraic numbers? The usual proof that the algebraic numbers are countable involves the proof that a degree-$n$ polynomial has at most $n$ roots, which is usually proven by picking a root and applying the factor theorem, and so does not yield an explicit bijection. Thus it would seem that this only characterizes the algebraic numbers as a countable union of finite sets, and so the bijection to $\Bbb N$ needs countable choice.

Comment: Suppose you take one root before another if its real part is bigger, and if they're equal then if its imaginary part is bigger.  So you don't need the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Hardy Ah yes, any finite subset of a totally ordered set is well-ordered. Alternatively, you could take advantage of the algebraic part to get a "nicer" total order on $\Bbb A$: take $\alpha<\beta$ iff $\Re\alpha+\pi\Im\alpha<\Re\beta+\pi\Im\beta$. This can not be zero for $\alpha\ne\beta$, because otherwise $\pi=\frac{\Re\beta-\Re\alpha}{\Im\alpha-\Im\beta}$ would be algebraic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this should be an answer, since it's not a proof but more heuristic evidence for a "no". This question is very similar to [Order preserving bijection from $\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542860/order-preserving-bijection-from-mathbb-q-times-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-q/545154#545154), but the difference is that the order on the real algebraic numbers is quite far removed from the means by which we enumerate them (in terms of coefficients and "root number"). Indeed I think that the problem would be solved if there was a nice closed form expression for the order predicate given a coding $\langle a_0,\dots,a_n,i\rangle$ of an algebraic number (the $i$-th root of $a_0+\dots+a_nx^n=0$). Even this coding is problematic because it doesn't eliminate double roots or imaginary roots, and "root number" is usually determined by sorting on real part, which is assuming the consequent in this case. So I think that you can't answer this question without making a breakthrough first in the representation and evaluation of polynomial roots.